# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have view like this

```
 <?php foreach((array)$query as $row): ?>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->id_jeans ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->nama ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->ket ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->tglmulai ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->tglselesai ?></td>
<?php $cari = $this->db->query("select sum(bahanbenang.biaya)
 FROM bahanbenang WHERE id_benang IN('$row->benang')"); ?>
  <td><?php echo $cari->result_array();?></td>
```

and error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

I anyone help me?

Comment: do not use echo since echo is for string and not array instead use print_r($array) or var_dump($array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure, but lets try this if you want echo an array

```
<?php 
    $cari = $this->db->query("select sum(bahanbenang.biaya)
                              FROM bahanbenang WHERE id_benang IN('$row->benang')");
    $result = $cari->result();
?>
<td><?php echo $result[0]->biaya;?></td>
```

Comment: solve dude thanks can I ask again? $row->benang in here have value has more value than one example = 1,2 but when I execute this $cari = $this->db->query("select sum(bahanbenang.biaya) FROM bahanbenang WHERE id_benang IN('$row->benang')") $row->benang = 1 ant (,2 not in $row->benang)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo $cari->result_array();?>
```

`echo` an array?. echo does not print arrays.

If you just want to print it to debug you can say

```
<?php print_r($cari->result_array());?>
```

Or you can loop over your array and print it nicely.

Just for the sake of completeness you  get that error because `echo` expects strings or things that can be implicitly converted to strings and you are sending it an array and that's what the error says exactly.